# Service worker not deleting old caches

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm using the code suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/adactio/fbaa3a5952774553f5e7) which is kind of a boilerplate to apply service workers.

I'm changing the variable `version` in an attempt to force a refresh of the cached files and a removal of the previous caches and, although I can in fact see how a new cache is created, I can't see the old ones getting removed.

[image]

Am I missing something?

```js
'use strict';

// Licensed under a CC0 1.0 Universal (CC0 1.0) Public Domain Dedication
// http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

(function() {

    // Update 'version' if you need to refresh the cache
    var staticCacheName = 'static';
    var version = 'v1::';

    // Store core files in a cache (including a page to display when offline)
    function updateStaticCache() {
        return caches.open(version + staticCacheName)
            .then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll([
                    '/path/to/javascript.js',
                    '/path/to/stylesheet.css',
                    '/path/to/someimage.png',
                    '/path/to/someotherimage.png',
                    '/',
                    '/offline.html'
                ]);
            });
    };

    self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(updateStaticCache());
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.keys()
                .then(function (keys) {
                    // Remove caches whose name is no longer valid
                    return Promise.all(keys
                        .filter(function (key) {
                          return key.indexOf(version) !== 0;
                        })
                        .map(function (key) {
                          return caches.delete(key);
                        })
                    );
                })
        );
    });

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
        var request = event.request;
        // Always fetch non-GET requests from the network
        if (request.method !== 'GET') {
            event.respondWith(
                fetch(request)
                    .catch(function () {
                        return caches.match('/offline.html');
                    })
            );
            return;
        }

        // For HTML requests, try the network first, fall back to the cache, finally the offline page
        if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') !== -1) {
            // Fix for Chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=573937
            if (request.mode != 'navigate') {
                request = new Request(request.url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: request.headers,
                    mode: request.mode,
                    credentials: request.credentials,
                    redirect: request.redirect
                });
            }
            event.respondWith(
                fetch(request)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // Stash a copy of this page in the cache
                        var copy = response.clone();
                        caches.open(version + staticCacheName)
                            .then(function (cache) {
                                cache.put(request, copy);
                            });
                        return response;
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        return caches.match(request)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                return response || caches.match('/offline.html');
                            })
                    })
            );
            return;
        }

        // For non-HTML requests, look in the cache first, fall back to the network
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response || fetch(request)
                        .catch(function () {
                            // If the request is for an image, show an offline placeholder
                            if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('image') !== -1) {
                                return new Response('<svg width="400" height="300" role="img" aria-labelledby="offline-title" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title id="offline-title">Offline</title><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M0 0h400v300H0z"/><text fill="#9B9B9B" font-family="Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-size="72" font-weight="bold"><tspan x="93" y="172">offline</tspan></text></g></svg>', { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml' }});
                            }
                        });
                })
        );
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

On each time updating the cache version in sw, browser will detect that the service worker got modified so browser starts to compile service worker from beginning(i.e from install event). The newly compiled sw will wait until the running sw got killed or suspended. After the running sw got killed, activate event of newly compiled sw will execute.In that state only older cache will be removed.
you can kill the running sw and activate the new sw by putting below line in install event

```js
self.skipwaiting();
```

To see more refer this link:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle